# R , binary files, floating points

Tags: r, binary, floating-point

I am trying to download and use rainfall data, preferably with R or Stata. The problem is that I have absolutely no clue about in what format the data is, and all the basic stuff. I am able to use geographical data in R, like using gps coordinates to color regions according to values of variables and similar things. Therefore I was wondering if it will work out the same way, but found really little information so far.

Just to get me started, which are the 3 most important things to know, in order to get started? Links to tutorials are very welcomed.

Here is the link of the data I am interested in
http://ftp.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/fews/S.Asia/data/
http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/data/indices/

Some new questions: following your links I found out it is indeed a binary file, 4-byte floating point, with 120701 points (observations). After reading in the (extracted) file:

```
to.read1 = file("cpc_rfe_v2.0_sa_dly.bin_1.20010501", "rb")
```

I have tried several things, for instance:

```
hhr <- readBin(to.read, integer(), n = 120701, 
      size = 4, endian = "big_endian")
```

which gives me the 120701 observations I am looking for, each composed by 10 integers. Is the option integer correct? How do I know that I am not supposed to be using "numeric". instead? What is really confusing is the "floating point". How do I know how many integers belong to the mantissa and how many to the exponent? I am following [this tutorial](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A-level_Computing/AQA/Problem_Solving,_Programming,_Operating_Systems,_Databases_and_Networking/Real_Numbers/Floating_point_numbers).

Comment: Looks like it is a binary file. this might help http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/read_binary.htm

Comment: Make sure to carefully read the documentation for the data: http://ftp.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/fews/S.Asia/SOUTH_ASIA_README.txt

Comment: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2001-February/011148.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [this r-help post](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2001-February/011148.html) (googled "R read single-precision float", I think):

```
hhr <- readBin(to.read1, numeric(), 
    n = 120701, size = 4, endian = "big_endian")
image(matrix(hhr,301,byrow=TRUE),
     col=gray((50:0)/50))
```

(I'm not sure this is right -- in particular it may be transposed -- but it seems reasonable)

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot! for whatever reason I believed I was suppsed to use integer() and convert it back to "normal" numbers. Using numeric indeed yields meaningful numbers, but I looked too easy :)